# Share ResourceDictionary across multiple Windows/WP apps

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am developing several apps for my company, each has its own solution and needs to look similar, as such I need a way to share resource dictionaries across apps. Using a shared library does not seem to be the correct way to go, since as I mentioned there are several solutions and cannot reference the shared library.

Is there a way to solve this other than manually copying all resources and duplicating them?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with Shared Libraries is a good approach. 
It does work with more than one solution and with more than one app. See Screenshot below showing 2 instances of VS with different solutions opened but all of them referencing the same SharedProject3.shproj at the same location on disk.

The trick is you have to choose "Add existing project" in the context menu of the solution and have to manually navigate to the *.shproj file of the shared 
project to add it. 
As soon as it appears in solution explorer you can reference it from one or more projects within your solution.
Whenever you add a file to the shared project in one solution it will also appear in the other solution .If it is openend at the same time you will get a hint that something changed. Make sure you save the project file (click "save all" ) before the hint will appear.

[image]

Comment: You're right, I was confused by the lack of binaries for some reason. Thank you, I guess I can then use this approach and reference it from the packages folder, and be delivered via Nuget.